# How to write to word document (in a particular format ) From C# windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, winforms-interop

I am developing a C# windows application , which captures the user's inputs(in the form of numerous textboxes, radio buttons and drop downs).

*I need to write the captured response from User to a word document which fits in the word document which has a predefined template.*

Could some one let me know the best way to approach that?

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how complex your needs are and the depth of your pockets there is a great product called [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).  We use their suite of products for generating office documents at work and they're really easy to work with.  It's unfortunately a pretty expensive product so unless you are very committed to your product it might not be right for you.

Otherwise you might want to check out [Microsoft's Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

[I have no affiliation with the company, aside from having used their products.]